# TypeScript inheritance static methods cast

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a TypeScript project with two classes BaseModel and HotelModel. The HotelModel extends the BaseModel class that provides some static methods like findById, all, etc..

```
export default class BaseModel {

  private collection:string
  _id:string | undefined

  constructor (collection:string) {
    this.collection = collection
  }

  static getCollectionName () {
    return this.prototype.constructor.name.toString().toLowerCase() + 's'
  }

  static async findById (id:string) {
    const connection = await getConnection()
    const hotel = await connection.collection(this.getCollectionName())
    .findOne({
      _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(id)
    })
    if (!hotel) {
      throw new ResourceNotFound('Hotel not found with the given id' + id)
    }
    return hotel
  }

}
```

and this is the HotelClass

```
import BaseModel from './baseModel'
import IHotel from '../interfaces/IHotel'

import ValidationException from '../../exceptions/ValidationException'

export default class Hotel extends BaseModel {

  name:string
  status:string
  metadata:object

  constructor (hotel:IHotel) {
    super('hotels')
    this.name = hotel.name
    this.status = hotel.status
    this.metadata = hotel.metadata
  }

  validate () {
    if (!this.name || this.name === '') {
      throw new ValidationException('Name field is required')
    }
  }

}
```

Now when i call HotelModel.findById(1) i would like to receive back an istance of the member class (HotelModel) is this possible? How can i achieve that?

**------UPDATE------**

based on suggestion this is what i got

```
export default class Service<T> {

  private collection:string

  constructor (collection:string) {
    this.collection = collection
  }

  async findById (id:string) {
    const connection = await getConnection()
    const model = await connection.collection(this.collection)
      .findOne({
        _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(id)
      }) as T
    if (!model) {
      throw new ResourceNotFound('Model not found with the given id' + id)
    }
    return model
  }

}
```

then i have a HotelService class that extends the generic one and inherits all the methods

```
export default class HotelService extends Service<HotelModel> {

  public constructor () {
    super('hotels')
  }

}
```

**------UPDATE 2------**

Well, it took quite a lot of time but I found an "elegant" (at least to me) solution to solve the problem

```
class QueryBuilder {

    private modelType: typeof BaseModel;

    constructor (modelType: typeof BaseModel) {
        this.modelType = modelType
    }

    data:Array<any> = [
        { id: '1', name: 'Jane' },
        { id: '2', name: 'John' },
        { id: '3', name: 'Mark' }
    ]

    findById (id:string) {
        // fake database call
        const data = this.data.find(r => r.id === id)
        // "cast" the database object to the required type
        let model:any = new this.modelType()
        model.fill(data)
        return model
    }
    
}

class BaseModel {

    private id:string | undefined

    constructor () {}

    static findById () {
        return new QueryBuilder(this)
            .findById('1')
    }

    public save () {
        console.log('calling save')
        this.id = '123456'
    }

    public fill (data:any) {
    }

}

class HotelModel extends BaseModel {

    public name:string | undefined

    constructor (
        name:string
    ) {
        super()
    }

}

let h:HotelModel = HotelModel.findById()
h.name = 'test name'
h.save()
console.log(h)
console.log(h instanceof HotelModel)
```

[PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECKCuBTATgTwELwJYgCYugG8AoY6c6AB2SwDcwAXRaAWwHt8QAVVSxALmgNeiNgDNo6SIgCyHRCADcpCtGBsAdhAbJ4wBm2TQAFO048%20g4X3GTpczgEoiZVRQYALLBAB0ZhRbMALys8twiruQAvioUuIxg-ACCyMhgqAA8YBqoAHzQIQDakW6E0Fi4ggDkAIxVADTQGmAsAtBVAFLZiFXQUfUlqmUV1QBMDU0tbZ1sHhq9-YMUw5XtAMwTza3VMmDIANYLJQC6seRiWBq46KgAkrgmI9o0GgDmziRuFAD039BiYH2zHiDDAACNpGowCAQEtyOotAxoCCwAUhF5fCifBcrsYjEF8sgfBUCkEQhVHHDoL9oAAiYCQBi09HAhIQiDMNhggBWiH0QjYLOgyEQAEdsCKHtZEFSQIgkf4QPxsqg0RpEAB3dHePxhQLGSlfciK7E4EDGFGGo0ihjwZAaUKcEoxVTEGLEUCQGBSDkOBQuErUOiMZhPHSXV7QAA%200HgV0QOMQuDOak0zz0BiMBqI7tU2kYWGA-0u1zuD2zn2t8rtDvVWoQKAw2DwKGMnm8VqNFFNVxu92MtSqnb6Kco8DBIEL0AgYFozArVIREDYcp8IDYrwHDJhEens56w9U7d8JJCtVGawALABWABsVWdo-Hk6LFxhJhRypyH0fbtInqgaAAAk2CYEA-RAaBEAADyYK5vXsMIA1UMcJynLYBGeXcYzjfBE2TEolx0DNDBMKkMP4LC3hKH8uwgeA%20GQA1f3dOUkQ8fgQLAiC0S4hQIJ7Ut%200pDwfAwtEqiYbRJlaB9RJnOdmKXFdEDXDdjA8SllNXddNw8cpEWyYBRAkPjwLCSlSCAA)

Thank you

Comment: You can use `return new this(found);`. However, TypeScript may refuse to type that properly. I would suggest to use a separate `Service<Hotel>` or (`Store` or whatever you want to call it) that can be made generic, instead of static methods.

Comment: Bergi suggestion is how I would do it to.

Comment: @Bergi Ok! I think I got it - make sense. I added my implementation, I hope I haven't made too many mistakes :D

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are after

```
export default class BaseModel {
  collection: string
  _id: string | undefined

  constructor(collection: string) {
    this.collection = collection;
  }

  static get collectionName() {
    return this.name.toLowerCase() + 's';
  }

  static async findById<T extends BaseModel>(
    this: (new (...args: any[]) => T) & Pick<typeof BaseModel, keyof typeof BaseModel>,
    id: string
  ): Promise<T> {
    const connection = await getConnection();
    const model = await connection.collection(this.collectionName)
      .findOne({
        _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(id)
      });
    if (!model) {
      throw new ResourceNotFound(`${this.collectionName} not found with the given id ${id}`);
    }
    return model as T;
  }
}

export default class Hotel extends BaseModel { ... }

const hotel = await Hotel.findOneBy('1');
console.log(hotel.name);
console.log(hotel.status);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gW1QcyWACMAueAb3gHkiArcDASWDJRAHd4AKADzMxgBLFHgCU8ALwA+eAFcUAaxRJ2KeAF8AsAChQkWAn1o08AEog0SWTDAgAckgwAxKymDwQPDCDcmAojAwSDAUGjp60HCI0MbwAGpQEILAUBiCqH48tgAOaageXj7A-oHBoVra4eCRCABm8mB5anggGADCqGyN6ShcomQACkHYgmggADyUyBAQDD1kXChQ2CD8GEIi4tKhtcLAVGwLsHhoZJQA+slk8koqaupbMkNII2PjN8qqMuoaUjo6nmywSwoFqUFkECwRhMACEoGMALKEEAQCj-bTweDZIQAN1ShiQMzmqDWGzwOkxlxY8AEwjw8AAPnI3CBdmxgOjMch0OtZI1glxprNuiSaes6eJyBTMfAMAALUYAOiFxLUEkQhOFTWlFWlmFSgjA8BaUM1qrsyxAfTRGJlcAw1jU8qV2McjgAntkQMrUAI+RhgoqlitFQGAMrikR9UNIAAyKhAMDa8Kt4gA1PAAORoTM6zlig1G+HulBGtnAGHu5jjAAqBW8vngcMRyIgUi4ztO3DYnC4iv7xy7UBQ7oA2gBdR7wGviABk8AGhoU4wwnpASFqTZTSNAEAANPAFCB3RvZWvT82QDuUVID1cxWTJdKub7TSguk1JPAoOwoIIsCaHTvqqfTPhqPLwHKjgol+P5-m+H49D6RIir0nbIVqPQWisohgZiirlgcVpSraMoylSrAcDg+CEEQio0PQjTMFwyS4aRMoPGBgiblwACEUHeBAT7sZi8pBJwPZmBYVg2PYjguPIwBcJmAAS0GosoWC1K47jsP+cqynKCB4IIOI+PAySZvAGasWBFRkfajqQep34mDWebaBUEQGGeXrwIwamCV+i5gMugUogeR4npu4VtgA3ACPBAjAUIxCYsX1kUsLbq2NrSsGqwPnSeoYKkshdrSIjSispUpKVZBIHQDD5tyfr8jAXACSiZABepwlkWgsheh1mZdRAOZsWR6EFV+Y1BpaYHofqDomOqc3LeVi0Kmgio1VAdVQLN6m7a0+2pFAHnSniSR1amNpkdx3C8dNlqMkyL0rJIEjqpmmb9WRhnifAkkJDdBoZFkIC5D0ynYXUggou4ozwHAACOsiCHAwB-XZl2eeisUEXslbMZmACMf2hkZvQ8JIMg8PNOFxUAA)

So, what's going on here?

We are using using TypeScript's ability to specify the type of the `this` value that functions and methods implicitly receive.

Since we are in a `static` method, the `this` type refers to the type of the class itself. That type is something we can call with `new` which is to say it is a constructor.

However, we want to capture the actual type of the derived class. To this end, we declare a generic type, `T`, that represents whatever a derived class returns when we call it with `new`. Then we state that `this` is a constructor that creates `T`s. We've lost access to the static members of the base class in doing so, however, and we have to add them back in with an intersection.

Finally, when we call `Hotel.findById`, TypeScript infers `T` from `typeof Hotel` because `typeof Hotel` is the type of the value `findById` is being called on.

***Note:*** Normally, the `this` type for `findById` would be simpler to write, i.e. `(new (...args: any[]) => T) & typeof BaseModel` but in this case, your derived class `Hotel` has a constructor with an incompatible argument list. I used `Pick<typeof BaseModel, keyof typeof BaseModel>` as a quick and dirty way to obtain a type containing all of the members of `typeof BaseModel` except call and construct signatures.

Comment: Well, chapeau dude, this is well explained and taught me a lot of typescript. Even if this make totally sense i feel like it is too much overcomplicated at least to a noob like me. So i found a more easier way to accomplish a similar result, even with static methods. Take a look if you got a chance.

Comment: I am glad you found it informative. I agree that simpler approaches are preferable. In fact, I would not recommend your original pattern but it is possible so I wanted to explain how. I also wouldn't use classes at all for this kind of thing because they are needlessly complicated. But you can if you want

Comment: I cannot access private or protected static properties using this (in BaseModel static method). How would I properly do that?

Comment: @sergiz that's not going to work. Don't use `private` or `protected` members.

Answer (score -1):

Overload static function of Hotel

```
  static async findById (id:string) {
    const data = await BaseModel.findById(id)
    return new Hotel(data)
  }
```

I'm not used to typescript so maybe someone can help me but following your update I think you need to pass the actual constructor value and not just a type

Here is an example

```
class Service {
   private collection: string
   private Model: any

   constructor (Model: any, collection: string) {
       this.collection = collection
       this.Model = Model
   }

   findById (id:string) {
    console.log(this.collection)
    return new this.Model(id)
  }
}

class HotelModel {
    public id: string
    constructor (id: string) {
        this.id = id
    }

    test () {
        return '1'
    }
}

class HotelService extends Service {
    constructor () {
        super(HotelModel, 'hotels')
    }
}

const hotelService = new HotelService()
const hotel = hotelService.findById('1')

console.log(hotel.test())
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmAnAbgS2PaBvAsAKGkIAdFVkwAXTYAexBHmAtRoDsAuaCC01gc3yFoJMpUwBZGgBN4ITmFYBPfIMK1W3RAFcmNRNAAUkmXOgLFAGmi16jZm06bU-AJTZVQwhQAWqCADobBiYWVmgAXms6YPtWD08fP39jWQjoFJAPAF8VAkIAM2cpACFFAEkpQ1QpdidXdzy1Ngg6eH8QGj4DRICgu1CXeMR4Ci1EMNZ4AHdoHuTpWQNqwbycvDX8UEgYAAkaKhAMhs8iLQAjEHRoasceZwFGqI0eHQo9KpquO-rcR4TfALVNLVeIbR5UbiGNy-TyeYajcbQADkAEYkaD8GCtlBoHsDggUOhMPAAB5UVhSGAEtAYY5CdSaV7vAzQ%20KeCBaIhIAx42QZKxI7z7WQQJErTxrLHNCjQIX4pA0zCRSYzXkgalElmbaWy4UgNJy2QajD%20QoU0oVAyosW5BmtdqdAyGkD%20CEUFkuIA)

I'm passing the actual class inside super and use it inside getFindId() to return the instance of this class.

Comment: will not work, BaseModel.findById returns promise and you are constructing Hotel with promise; also probably new Hotel() on data is undesirable.

Comment: Yes but I dont like this solution, look at my second update, is totally different code structure but I like it better.

Comment: Understandable and I'm glad that we could guide you in finding a solution.